# How do I know if the given points of a rectangle are in order with respect to the border of rectangle?

Tags: math

According to the question, the following points don't respect the order, which I don't understand:

Point 1:
0 0
Point 2:
20 0
Point 3:
0 50
Point 4:
20 50

Would someone explain that to me please?

Comment: Have you taken a piece of graph paper and drawn these points on it, then connected them in order ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out programmatically. Is there an equation or something to do it with?

Comment: Draw the line from pt1 to pt2.  Measure the angle between that line and the line from pt2 to pt3, ... Or use the answer below.

Comment: "don't respect the order": what order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if points are in order, you need to follow the same path that you would have done on a paper.
Draw a rectangle on a paper and named points A(xA,xB), B(xB,yB), C(xC,yC) and D(xD,yD) in order.

Start with your pen on the A. To go from A to B, there is an euclidian equation (`y=mx+p`)(1).
`m` is the slope and `b` the intercept. Find more info on [Wikipedia - Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#Cartesian_plane) 
for the line between A and B

`m = (yb − ya)/(xb − xa)`

`p = m(x − xa) + ya`

Then you can find the equation replacing `m` and `p` on (1).

When you have this equation, you need to find the second one (between B and C)

When you have both line equation you apply [Line-line intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection)

If there is an intersection, points aren't in order. If there isn't, you apply the same algorithm between with lines BC and CD. Check again if there is an intersection. If not, do it a third time with CD and DA.

Comment: Would you please elaborate? I'm very slow with maths and would appreciate more help/explanation. thanks!

Comment: I've added a lot details on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that assumes

1. an axis parallel rectangle,
2. the only allowed order being lower left, lower right, upper right, upper left (Y pointing upward).

   Ok == P0.X < P1.X && P1.Y < P2.Y && P2.X > P3.X && P3.Y > P0.Y

If the sequence is allowed to shift, keeping the same order, one can replicate this formula four times, and OR them.